# How to refer to the input field by name

Tags: jquery

How should I refer to the input field in my JS code?

```
input[name="email"]
```

Is not quit right.

```
$("#reg-form").find('input[name="email"]').parent("").addClass('has-error');
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">EMAIL</label><span> *</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_details[email]">
    <div class="help-block"></div>
    <!-- errors will go here -->
</div>
```

Comment: You dont have an input named email

Comment: @AlexThomas -  I have - user_details[email]

Comment: @rol - no - you have one named - user_details[email]

Answer (score 2):

Your `input` is not named 'email', you need to include the full name while remembering to escape the square brackets. Try this:

```
$("#reg-form").find('input[name="user_details\\[email\\]"]').parent().addClass('has-error');
```

Also note that `""` isn't a valid selector for `parent()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.find("input[type='text']")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="user_details\\[email\\]"]');
```

Try like this.

You don't have input with `name="email"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

There is no element named `email`, your input name is `user_details[email]`.

Also there is no need for empty selector in `.parent()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#reg-form")
    .find('input[name="user_details[email]"]')
    .parent()
    .addClass('has-error')
  ;
});
```

```css
.has-error label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reg-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">EMAIL</label><span> *</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_details[email]">
    <div class="help-block"></div>
    <!-- errors will go here -->
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
$('input[name="user_details[email]"]')
```